# Can I specify join strategy right in a django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Is there a way to specify a join strategy not in a query (with `prefetch_related` or `select_related`), but right in a django model (like `lazy='joined'` in sqlalchemy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a manager to automatically apply `select_related` and/or `prefetch_related`. For example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).select_related(
            'user'
        )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_deleted=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    objects = ProfileManager()
```

If you then access `Profile.objects.all()`, then it will automatically perform a `.select_related()`.